# Reformatting a Contingency Table

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a code that counts the number of times an insect family is present in each location. At the moment, I can't find a way to do this without manually counting, which isn't possible for the dataset size I'm going to be working with. Right now I have this:

```
Location       Family
ORCHARD        Anthicidae
ORCHARD        Anthicidae
ROCKY          Trogossitidae
ORCHARD        Meloidae
ROCKY          Elateridae
ROCKY          Cleridae
ORCHARD        Silphidae
FARM           Meloidae
ROCKY          Dermestidae
ORCHARD        Trogossitidae
FARM           Elateridae
FARM           Elateridae
ORCHARD        Anthicidae
```

This is what I'd like it to look like:

```
Family           Orchard Rocky Farm
Anthicidae          2      0     0
Trogossitidae       0      1     0
Meloidae            1      0     0
Elateridae          0      1     2
...
```

Does anyone have a better (non-manual) way to go about this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just do `table(df)`

Comment: Well ... technically `t(table(df))` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Update: A very good tip @onyambu (many thanks):
We could omit `count`:

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, Family, names_from = Location, values_from = Location, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

**First answer:**

After using `count`, that groups by and summarises, we could use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  count(Family, Location) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Location, values_from= n, values_fill = 0)
```

```
Family        ORCHARD ROCKY  FARM
  <chr>           <int> <int> <int>
1 Anthicidae          3     0     0
2 Cleridae            0     1     0
3 Dermestidae         0     1     0
4 Elateridae          0     1     2
5 Meloidae            1     0     1
6 Silphidae           1     0     0
7 Trogossitidae       1     1     0
```

Comment: (did not downvote). If you are using `pivot_wider` why use `count`? just do `pivot_wider(df, Family, names_from = Location, values_from = Location, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)`